# git rebase with conflict not work

Tags: git, rebase

I have remote repository.
I do:

```
git clone https://mylogin@bitbucket.org/mylogin/myrepo.git
```

Clone success.
I have git tree:
C(master)
|    B:A
|    /
B /
|
A
|
A0
|
A01(origin/head)(origin/master)
|
(some commits)

I need:
                B:A
C(master) /

I need rebase branch B  to C(master)
What I do:

```
git checkout b1
Switched to branch 'b1'
git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: B:A
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M   index1.txt
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging index1.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in index1.txt
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 B:A
The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
   /pth/to dir/.git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".

git branch
* (no branch)
  b1
  master
```

What must I do?
I can switch in branch b1, resolve conflict and commit, but it not help (I tested it).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Git will stop rebasing if it detects conflicts it cannot automatically resolve. In your case, you have a conflict in the file `index1.txt` (you can see it in the output, and later on as well when running `git status`). You must fix the conflicts before continuing. Edit the file, and you'll see `<<<<<<`, `======` and `>>>>>>` markers. The conflict is in those lines, where what's between the `<` and the `=` is the changes in master, and after that (until the `>`) is the changes in branch `b1`. Fix it, remove the git markers (`<`,`=`,`>`), then run `git add index1.txt`, and move on to the next file (if you have any, in this example only `index1.txt` conflicts). Once you're done adding all files, run `git rebase --continue`. If git encounters another conflict, simply repeat the process for each file(s) it has problems with. Once you're done, git will tell you that rebase has successfully finished, and you'll be back on branch `b1`. If you want to stop the process and return to the original `b1` (before the rebase command), simply run `git rebase --abort`.

Remember that when you fix conflicts, don't edit the file to be as it should be in your final commit, rather only introduce the changes you wanted for that specific commit. Other changes will be added as git continues rebasing and applying your commits.

Comment: "don't edit the file to be as it should be in your final commit, rather only introduce the changes you wanted for that specific commit" +1. I was wondering how come these lines of code are still there, when I changed them!

Comment: Note that you should edit the file with the conflict (`index1.txt` in your case), not the `patch` file. `patch` is just there to reference if you are unsure what change is being rebased.